# Pyspark dataframe .show() works fine but .count() gives error

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe `stage_name_valid_df` which looks like follows on calling `.show()`

[image]

and .toPandas() works as well

[image]

but on calling `stage_name_valid_df.count()` I get an error as shown below. What could be the possible cause of it? My java version is `openjdk version "1.8.0_342"` and I am running pyspark locally on my laptop. Pyspark version is `3.3.0` and python version is `3.9.12`.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't find revision_id#17L in [stage_name#116,sum#1397L]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1.applyOrElse(BoundAttribute.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1.applyOrElse(BoundAttribute.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:589)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:698)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:589)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:528)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$.bindReference(BoundAttribute.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.GenerateExec.boundGenerator$lzycompute(GenerateExec.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.GenerateExec.boundGenerator(GenerateExec.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.GenerateExec.$anonfun$doExecute$3(GenerateExec.scala:95)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:486)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:492)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$ConcatIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage5.hashAgg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage5.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

A complete program to reproduce the error is below (although with a minimal toy dataset):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType, StringType, IntegerType, ArrayType, StructType, StructField
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

import random
random_seed = 901
random.seed(random_seed)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple test") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "16g").config("spark.executor.memory", "16g") \
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("2009-07-14 08:38:31",11757,"ABC"),
        ("2009-10-06 10:13:45",34941,"ABC"),
        ("2009-03-10 09:31:00",40285,"ABC"),
        ("2009-10-15 08:42:37",41041,"ABC"),
        ("2009-10-26 10:52:48",49115,"ABC"),
        ("2009-10-26 13:43:30",49435,"ABC"),
        ("2009-11-04 14:04:33",57809,"ABC"),
        ("2009-11-12 00:00:00",66343,"ABC"),
        ("2009-11-18 12:47:27",72714,"ABC"),
        ("2009-11-20 10:27:09",74859,"ABC"),
        ("2009-11-20 13:38:22",75241,"ABC"),
        ("2009-11-25 14:36:59",80216,"ABC"),
        ("2009-11-26 15:14:49",81691,"ABC"),
        ("2009-11-27 14:56:52",83128,"ABC"),
        ("2009-12-02 08:18:56",86670,"ABC"),
        ("2009-12-08 13:07:56",93710,"ABC"),
        ("2009-12-15 12:34:20",101225,"ABC"),
        ("2009-12-17 08:58:19",103576,"ABC"),
        ("2009-12-17 10:23:30",103806,"ABC"),
        ("2010-01-12 12:46:38",118869,"ABC"),
        ("2010-01-12 13:57:17",119030,"ABC"),
        ("2010-01-18 11:25:59",124378,"ABC")
    ],
    ["revision_date", "revision_id", "cat_name"]
)

# Perform Stratified split. I know that stratified split doesn't make sense for a single `cat_name` type in the toy dataset here but I am preparaing the pipeline for actual dataset.

fractions1 = df.select("cat_name").distinct().withColumn("fraction", F.lit(0.6)).rdd.collectAsMap()

stage_name_train_df = df.stat.sampleBy("cat_name", fractions1, random_seed)

rest_df = df.exceptAll(stage_name_train_df)

fractions2 = {key: 0.5 for key, value in fractions1.items()} 

stage_name_valid_df = rest_df.stat.sampleBy("cat_name", fractions2, random_seed)

stage_name_test_df = rest_df.exceptAll(stage_name_valid_df)



stage_name_valid_df.show() # This works fine.
stage_name_valid_df.toPandas()  # This works fine as well.
stage_name_valid_df.count() # This gives error.
```

Comment: how is `stage_name_valid_df` built ? just a read from a file/table ? or a lot of compute steps ?

Comment: Also, what error are you getting?  Could you post stacktrace?

Comment: @Steven: The `stage_name_valid_df` is the result of `sampleBy()` on a source dataframe read from a file.

Comment: It says `Couldn't find revision_id#17L in [stage_name#116,sum#1397L]`. The dataframe at one of your function calls contains only `stage_name` and `sum` columns and the function is trying to access `revision_id` column. Do you know at which point you have the dataframe with columns `stage_name` and `sum`? Please add some code leading up to `count` for us to debug further.

Comment: @Emma Please see the updates I made in my question. I have uploaded a complete code to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem vanished when I used a lower version of pyspark. After uninstalling pyspark `3.3.0` and installing `3.1.2`, everything worked as expected.

Comment: I was able to replicate your issue and it seems that combination of `sampleBy` and `exceptAll` is making the issue. If I change `exceptAll` to left-anti join (`df.join(stage_name_train_df, on=df.columns, how='left_anti').count()`), the error disappeared.  My 2 cents is somehow this is affecting: Sample push down is introduced in 3.3.0 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-37038). I am not sure, though.

Comment: I have same issue, just updated pyspark to 3.3.0 and my tests failed.
In my case error appears when I run `.count()` after `.exceptAll()`

Comment: @cuZzior same happened to me, test failing after upgrade, in my case, I am using exceptAll() after count()